# Multiple definition with 2 header files

Tags: c++, header-files, multiple-definition-error

I am using CodeBlocks.

In C++, I have 3 header files and 3 cpp files like below.

**Base.h**

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual int funky(int x, int y);
};
```

**Base.cpp**

```
 int funky(int x, int y) {
  return x+y;
}
```

**FirstClass.h**

```
class FirstClass: public Base
{
public:
    virtual int funky(int x, int y);
};
```

**FirstClass.cpp**

```
int funky(int x, int y) {
  return x+y;
}
```

**SecondClass.h**

```
class SecondClass: public Base
{
public:
    virtual int funky(int x, int y);
};
```

**SecondClass.cpp**

```
int funky(int x, int y) {
  return x+y;
}
```

In this condition I take error of "multiple definition." But, I have to use these functions with the same names.
I tried

```
int funky (int x, int y) override;
```

but it did not work.

I need all three function, because when I want to call them like below and if they are defined like above, I cannot reach them.

```
 vector<Base> BASE =  {FirstClass(), SecondClass()};
 BASE[1]->funky(1,2)
```

Do you have any suggestion? I am open to another approach to this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: You want `FirstClass::funky` in `FirstClass.cpp` and `SecondClass::funky` in `SecondClass.cpp`.

Comment: How is that `vector<Base> BASE` working out? it seems the accepted answer doesn't mention that, or the need for a `virtual` base class destructor, at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above code sample, you defining funky in two different cpp files but have declared in your class. So following should be the correct format:

##### FirstClass.cpp

```
int FirstClass::funky(int x, int y) {
  return x+y;
}
```

##### SecondClass.cpp

```
int SecondClass::funky(int x, int y) {
  return x+y;
}
```

##### main.cpp

```
FirstClass a;
SecondClass b;

cout<<a.funky(1,2)<<" "<<b.funky(3,4)<<endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

`int funky(int x, int y)` in both your `.cpp` files are defined as free functions that has nothing to do with the classes you've defined. They have the same signature and you therefore get a linking problem with multiple definitions.

I suggest you make the destructor in the base class `virtual`, just in case you want to destroy objects through a base class pointer.

Inheriting, overriding and defining the member functions could look like this:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;           // virtual destructor
    virtual int funky(int x, int y) = 0; // = 0 added to make it pure virtual
};
```

```
class FirstClass : public Base {         // inherit
public:
    int funky(int x, int y) override;    // now you can override
};
```

```
int FirstClass::funky(int x, int y) {    // class member function definition
    return x+y;
}
```

And you need to do the same for `SecondClass`.

You should not use `vector<Base>` though. You will not store `Base` objects but most probably pointers to objects of types derived from `Base`, like `FirstClass` and `SecondClass`. I suggest using the smart pointer [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for this:

```
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> BASE;

    BASE.emplace_back(std::make_unique<FirstClass>());
    BASE.emplace_back(std::make_unique<SecondClass>());
    
    std::cout << BASE[0]->funky(2,3) << '\n';
    std::cout << BASE[1]->funky(2,3) << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M136xvWjx)